# Android Studio error message "Unable to resolve dependency"

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

What does the error seen in the editor mean? I would love to see a fully explained answer.

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/MAHE/AndroidStudioProjects/Dork_1/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.">Show Details</a>
```

[image]
[image]

I am using **Android Studio 3.0**

```
Error Code---
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task '~offline' not found in root project 'Dork_1'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

Comment: Edit your question and give appropriate details

Comment: pls help..i am not able to understand it myself!

Comment: your question is incomplete

Comment: Your image url are missing

Comment: Sorry... I uploaded the images

Comment: Can I get the reply fast???

Comment: Anyone there!.....

Comment: IMAGE LINKS http://res.cloudinary.com/da0ej2qkq/image/upload/v1512227559/error_1_dzus0m.png http://res.cloudinary.com/da0ej2qkq/image/upload/v1512227582/erroe_2_nviayj.png

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens because of internet connection problems. Make sure you have 
a good connection.
sometimes it happens because of google limitations for some countries. If you live in that countries, you have to add this library manually.